# How to use NSStreamEvents in Swift?

Tags: xcode, events, event-handling, swift, nsstream

I have trouble using the events my NSStream objects throw.

In obj C it is something like this:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    switch (streamEvent) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        break;          
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}
```

How do i do that in Swift? i don't understand the NSStreamEvent reference. In Obj C its an Enum And in swift its a struct. Any ideas on how to use this like the above example?

Answer (score 0):

NSStreamEvent conforms to `OptionSetType` in Swift 2: it's defined as a `struct` with `static var`s for each of the possible values, so you can use it like an enum.

From [Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID169):

> In Swift, option sets are represented by structures conforming to the OptionSetType protocol, with static variables for each option value. Option sets behave like Swift’s Set collection type. You use the `insert(_:)` or `unionInPlace(_:)` methods to add option values, the `remove(_:)` or `subtractInPlace(_:)` methods to remove option values, and the `contains(_:)` method to check for an option value. You create a new option set value using an array literal, accessing option values with a leading dot (`.`) similar to an enumeration. An empty option set can be created from an empty array literal (`[]`) or by calling its default initializer.